# Looking for a sql command to find active triggers, and their associated tables

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to find active triggers and their associated tables in Sybase. What would be a written query?

I found the following SQL command useful
`select *  from sysobjects  where type = "TR"  where deltrig =1 or instrig = 1 or updtrig =1`

But, I do not know how to associate the trigger name with the name of a table.

Comment: I think it is `sysdepends`

Comment: please confirm which Sybase RDBMS (SQLAnywhere aka ASA? ASE?) and version you're using; `sysobjects` is ASE, but you've flagged the question as ASA ... these are two different products with different names/structures for their metadata; for ASA I'd start with the `SYSTRIGGERS` view and/or the source code for any system procs that display trigger info; for ASE I'd start with the `sp_depends` stored proc, and if you're running ASE 16 you could also look at `sp_helptrigger`; if stored procs are able to provide the desired info but not in a usable format then review said proc's source code